# Facebook like button confusion

Tags: html, facebook, button, facebook-like

I am trying to understand how the code for a like button works. As of right now, I have spent 3 hours looking into this and still don't understand it. Most of my frustration is on: Why do I need an App ID in order to have a like button for my page? Can someone help explain this to me and help me understand how to fully setup this like button?

Answer (score 0):

You need an App ID to use the Facebook API. There are alternatives if you don't want to go down that route:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

If you do however then take a look here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.2

Comment: what would those alternates be?

Comment: Okay, i guess it might just be an error on my end. Im not sure. Ive already looked into this too long. Going to sleep. Thank you for helping

Comment: No problem, the alternative is here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button you simply set the url to "like" and embed it